# How to make child process die whenever parent process gets restarted

Tags: c, linux, process, daemon, kill

Daemon **X** spawns process **Y**. Sometimes daemon **X** could die abruptly and in that case it did not have a chance to properly terminate its child process **Y** (that is, process **Y** would remain running in the background). *How to make sure that **Y** gets always terminated whenever **X** abruptly died?*

Currently I have implemented daemon **X** in a such way that, if it abruptly died, then it gets restarted; reads process' **Y** pid file and terminates **Y** by using `kill(pid, SIGTERM)`. This solution, however, has its drawbacks - before killing process **Y**, I need to make sure that it is indeed process **Y** (because some other newer process could be reusing the same pid that was in **Y**'s pid file). Even, if **X** checks process' **Y** name against `/proc/<pid>/`, then there is still a small window where theoretically **X** could be killing wrong process.

Since process **Y** is not developed by me, I can't use `prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGTERM)` from **Y**.

Also, `system("killall Y")` is too broad for my use case.

Is there a better way to solve this problem than what I currently have?

Comment: how you identify process Y if "killall Y" is not your case.Are there other processes also named Y?You check both pid and process name?

Comment: There could be multiple X instances running at the same time. Each X could have multiple Ys. If new X1 instance would do "killall Y", then it would interfere with X2 by killing its children. However, new X1 knows all pid files that were created as result of old X1.

Answer (score 4):

The process groups/sessions are probably the way to go. How about this:

If **X** does `setsid()`, remove it from the code. Write a very simple wrapper shell script to run the daemon:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/xd || pkill -TERM -s 0
```

and run it with `setsid` command. If the daemon process exits abnormally, `pkill` will send fatal signal to all processes in the current session. The session is inherited through `fork()`/`exec()`, and the session leader (shell process) still exists when `pkill` is executed, so unless child does `setsid()` as well, there is no chance of child escaping or killing the wrong process.

Comment: how to do that with multiple commands, not only xd, so that if the master process ends then the children also do?

Answer (score 0):

For Linux **only**:

Using the function [`prctl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) with option `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG` allows the <strike>parent</strike> child to set a signal that is send to <strike>their children</strike> to it in case the parent dies. The applies only to children created after this option had been set.

Verbatim from the Linux man page for `ptctl()`:

> **PR_SET_PDEATHSIG** (since Linux 2.1.57)
>
> Set the parent process death signal of the calling process to
>                 arg2 (either a signal value in the range 1..maxsig, or 0 to
>                 clear).  This is the signal that the calling process will get
>                 when its parent dies.  This value is cleared for the child of
>                 a fork(2) and (since Linux 2.4.36 / 2.6.23) when executing a
>                 set-user-ID or set-group-ID binary.

Comment: According to man page it works the reverse way. Child has to do prctl() and then it will be notified when parent died. Unfortunately, patching child is not an option for me.

Comment: @AnsisAtteka: Dxxmn, you're right, sry for having mixed this up. Corrected.

Comment: As long as the thing you are `exec()`ing is not a setsid/setgid it will inherit a `prctrl` done right before calling `exec()`.

Comment: @AnsisAtteka: That's what I wanted to mention, just do the call to `prctl()` as the 1st thing after the `fork()`. There will however still be a race, if the child decides to crash after being `fork()`ed and before having placed the call to `prctl()`.